# javascript split array in two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to split this array into two different arrays using the values inside the first array.

This is my initial array:

```
    "carList": [
      {
        "brand": [
          {
            "model": [
              { "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 10 },
              { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 20 },
              { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 30 },
              { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 40 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { "brand": [{ "model": [{ "size": 400 }] }] },
      { "brand": [{ "model": [{ "size": 500 }] }] }
    ],
```

The first array must contain the model with the motor and the colors. The second should only contain the brand with the size (I can have an indeterminate number of brands).

I would like this as an output:

```
    "carList": [
      {
        "brand": [
          {
            "model": [
              { "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 10 },
              { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 20 },
              { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 30 },
              { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 40 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
```

```
    "carList": [
      { "brand": [{ "model": [{ "size": 400 }] }] },
      { "brand": [{ "model": [{ "size": 500 }] }] }
    ],
```

When trying to split the array, I tried to create the array only with size, but I get the carList global:

```
const carList1 = carList.filter((x) =>
    x.brand.filter((y) => y.model.filter((z) => z.size)
   );
```

How I can split my array and get this output?

**UPDATE**
This is my more genral exemple test I can have many brand and model,

```
   "carList": [
      {
        "brand": [
          {
            "model": [
              { "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 10 },
              { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 20 },
              { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 30 },
              { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 40 }
            ]
          },
          {
            "model": [
              { "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 11 },
              { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 22 },
              { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 33 },
              { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 44 }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { "brand": [
         { 
           "model": [
             { "size": 400 },
           ]
         },
         {
            "model": [
             { "size": 401 }
           ]
         },
      { "brand": [{ "model": [{ "size": 500 }] }] }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way of doing it:

```js
const data={"carList":[
   {"brand":[{"model": [{ "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 10 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 20 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 30 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 40 }]},
             {"model": [{ "motor": { "id": 1 }, "color": 11 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 2 }, "color": 22 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 3 }, "color": 33 },
                        { "motor": { "id": 4 }, "color": 44 }]}
            ]},
   {"brand":[{"model": [{ "size": 400 }]},
             {"model": [{ "size": 401 }]}]},
   {"brand":[{"model": [{ "size": 500 }]}]} 
]}

const [mo,si]=["motor","size"].map(p=>data.carList.filter(e=>
  e.brand.find(b=>b.model.find(m=>m[p]))));

console.log(JSON.stringify(mo));
console.log(JSON.stringify(si));
```

I applied the snippet now to the updated data. The result arrays `motor` and `sizes` are calculated by applying a `.filter()` on the `data` array.

In this updated version of the script I assign a `brand` to the `mo` or `si` array if it somehow contains the property `motor` or size`.

Comment: Yes its works but if i have two models in the brand like that :

Comment: Could you maybe extend your sample data to show this more general test case and explain exactly _what you would like to happen_, if in one `brand` branch we should find _both_, a `motor` _and_ a `size` type model.

Comment: I update my exemple with the more general test case

Comment: I can have a number inderterminate of model, brand, i must loop on the brand

Comment: thank you @Carsten Massmann,  it's perfect i can adapt for my project